# pythonanywhere website db query return jsonify result

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I don't understand pythonanywhere website ,how to return json key value,but localhost only return value **not key** ??

env

1.flask

2.SQLAlchemy

3.mysql

4.python 2.7

my orm class

```
Base = declarative_base()
class DataEntity(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'data'
      id = Column("id", INTEGER, primary_key=True, nullable=False,autoincrement=True)
      clientid= Column("client_id", VARCHAR(32),nullable=False)
      name= Column("name", VARCHAR(10),nullable=False)
      description= Column("description", VARCHAR(20),nullable=False)
```

my flask_app.py

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://xxx:xxx@xxx.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/xxx$dbname?charset=utf8', echo=True,pool_recycle=280)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
dbsession = Session()

@app.route('/api/data')
def getdata():
    data = dbsession.query(DataEntity.id,DataEntity.name).all();
    return jsonify({'data': data})
```

pythonanywhere website json result

```
{"data": [{"id": 1,"name": "name1"},{"id": 2,"name": "name2"}]}
```

local json result

```
{"data": [[1,"name1"],[2,"name2"]]}
```

Comment: Are you sure to have the same versions ? (you can check it with `pip freeze`)

Comment: @AugustinLaville
i try service version but not working.
[pythonanywhere website requirement.txt](https://gist.github.com/leejulee/bf0bf35159d373f9de0f35eac265d44b)

Comment: does this help? http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs